# How do I choose a unique value in relation to an array unloaded from the database?

Tags: php, redbean

When adding an item to the database, you must assign a unique key to it. 
Numeric is not suitable, since can parse simply iterate over all the products.

**How do I do a unique verification cycle correctly?** 
Which will generate the key until there are no duplicates.

`uniqid();` generates the appropriate keys, but does not guarantee the uniqueness of the value, so I decided to check with the existing keys.

Downloading a column with keys from the database

```
$arrayAllKey = R::getAll('SELECT `category_key` FROM `items` WHERE `id_user` = 104);
```

[image]

Searching and comparing each element of the array will be expensive if there is a large amount of data.
Therefore, the best option is to select a specific value from the database.

Unsuccessfully made a code where:
**$unique** - key generated using uniqid()
**$arrayAllKey** - array of existing keys
**$findedKey**- selecting a cell from a database with a key
**$arr[0]["category_key"]** - value of the found key $findedKey

```
// writing the key that is in the database
$unique = "5e9dfcc637f75"; 

// Taking the value of the generated key $unique
// If it finds a value, it will output it; if it doesn't, it won't output anything
$findedKey = R::getAll('SELECT `category_key` FROM `items` WHERE `id_user` = ? and `category_key` = ?', [104, $unique]); 

// If the value of the found key is present
if ($findedKey[0]["category_key"]) {
    // generating a new key
    $unique = uniqid(); 
    // selecting the value from the database again
    $findedKey = R::getAll('SELECT `category_key` FROM `items` WHERE `id_user` = ? and `category_key` = ?', [104, $unique]);
} else {
    // if no duplicates are found, output a unique key
    echo $unique;
};
```

Comment: Is it an option to generate a UUID/GUID?

Comment: You should generate a random unique-key and try inserting until it works, regenerating the unique-key each time (with a bail out after e.g. 100 attempts to avoid endless loops, if this happens you would have to change your generation algorithm) -> have a unique database index for this in place

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Do You have a sample code for how it can work?

Comment: The first example for `random_bytes` [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) will give you something significantly random that it's not likely to exist already. That said if you index your category_key column it won't be too long to search.

Comment: Sorry, I don't plan to generate cool keys, I just want to check if there is such a key in the database, and if not, save it.

Comment: In that case I'd just insert with SQL's `UUID()` for your key on a unique column, and handle the duplicate error if thrown (which is very low chance)

Comment: 12 bytes of hex = ~281 trillion possibilities. I wouldn't worry about collisions too much.